# Why aren't there props for child -> parent and $emits for parent -> child?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a page with a component and the page needs to access a variable in that component and it needs to be reactive. Then from the page I need to activate a function in the component. Would be nice if it could be done without a reactive variable. My question is 1: what's the best way to activate the function from the parent, for example when I click a button and 2: it seems very unintuitive and random to me that they aren't both possible in both directions? Anyone maybe know how Vue suggest you do it? This whole thing seems so complex relative to the relatively simple thing I'm trying to do.

I guess I try to use props? Or are refs a better option here?

Comment: Also semi-unrelated but I don't find the Vue documentation very good which I don't get because everyone says it's pretty good. Just my opinion but I find most documentation to be as if it's directed at already experienced people (or the devs are paranoid about amnesia). Does it get easier once you get better at Vue?

Comment: I believe the original intent was that if you designed your application so that communication only flows in one direction you have an easier time debugging. Besides refs another cool way is using a store for all data - [Vuex for example](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/). Your application then should react to the data as much as possible. Directly calling functions should be reserved for edge cases.

Comment: @PeterKrebs That's why I wish I could use props for child->parent, because I wouldn't have to use emits.

Comment: Understandable, but that cannot work efficiently in large apps. Every parent would have to send a message to every child regardless if needed or not. I have created excel-looking sheets with cells where Vue allowed us to only update exactly a specific cell instead of pumping 1000 messages to all child components. Anyway, working with a Store helps there, maybe take a look at Vuex I linked above.

Comment: @PeterKrebs And why does that only apply to child->parent and not parent->child? With your logic props shouldn't exist at all. Which I wouldn't mind, since you could use emits, I just want it to be consistent and not feel like every function is random

Comment: Well again because updating every child when an update happens would be slow. Also data stores like Vuex exist so why implement a feature that's not needed? Vue is not designed to give you every freedom ever. It was designed to make a reactive workflow happen and whatever they had to do to make that fast in browsers is what you have to live with for now. You are welcome to take Vue and make it better though.

Comment: ok and how do i do that?

Comment: The community welcomes your feedback: https://github.com/vuejs/core/discussions - either way changing a value in the props will cause a re-rendering of child components. But child components have to emit to the parent if they changed the value. Otherwise you would experience slow behavior or flickering.

Answer (score 3):

So in general: you use refs, if you need the dom element, that's the whole purpose of refs. Since you don't mention that you n ed the dom element, you don't need to use that here.

There are 3 ways of communication: parent to child via props: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

child to parent via events
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

and anyone to anyone via event bus, which need an extra lib in vue3 and is out of scope for your question
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus

If you want to execute a function in the component whenever the value changes, you can put a watcher on the prop.
The other way around, from child to parent, you just create a listener to your emitted event and invoke a function of your choice. There are good examples in the docs in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to trigger the child component method from the `Parent` component without passing any prop as a input parameter and in same way you want to access child component data in the parent component without `$emit`. If Yes, You can simply achieve this using `$refs`.

You can attach the `ref` to the child component and then access it's variables and methods with the help of this `$refs`.

Live Demo (Just for a demo purpose I am using Vue 2, You can make the changes as per Vue 3) **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  data: {
    childVar: ''
  },
  methods: {
    triggerEventInChildFromParent() {
      console.log('Child Function triggered from Parent');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.childVar = 'Child component variable'
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    triggerEventInChild() {
      this.$refs.child.triggerEventInChildFromParent()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.child.childVar)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="triggerEventInChild">
    Button in Parent
  </button>
  <child ref="child"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: What about in a single file component?